# Youtube Analytics Reports updated Timestamp

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics

I'm using Youtube Analytics API in our app and my client would like to know when does the analytics reports get updated? It was mentioned in the documentation that the data is updated on daily basis like every 24 hrs. So, question is will all the reports are updated at the same time or they will be updated on rolling basis, like some of the reports at some time and other reports at a different time?

Also, I would like to use the last updated Time stamp of the reports. Is it possible to get the last updated timestamp of the reports?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you should use Youtube API to get list of reports for a specific job ([check here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports/list))

The sample results will look like:

```
 "reports": [
  {
   "id": "392226189",
   "jobId": "0e2184aa-eaec-4377-94d9-bo8ff5dcd020",
   "startTime": "2016-08-19T07:00:00Z",
   "endTime": "2016-08-20T07:00:00Z",
   "createTime": "2016-11-23T03:26:37.232661Z",
   "downloadUrl": `enter code here`"https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/media/CHANNEL/Vtt8H9XtcLB1G79QUCgdu0g/jobs/0e2184aa-eaec-4377-94d9-bo8ff5dcd020/reports/392226189?alt=media"
  }]

```
You can use `createTime` to check wheather report is updated or not. If reports is updated, `createTime` will be different with first `createTime` you had gotten before.

[Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/)

`Use the report ID to identify reports that you still need to download and import. However, if two new reports have the same startTime and endTime property values, only import the report with the newer createTime value.`